# How can I extract email address after document.write execution

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

I am making an Application using C# and ASP.Net  that will grab all the email addresses from the specific URL , for that , I am garbing the innerHTML , using

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString("abc");
        return downloadString;
```

Problem is that in innerHTML , the Email Address Portion is in encoded array of Javascript that is rendered by document.write , so I am unable to grab the email address , I have a good regex to identify email addresses , as it is identifying all other email addresses except the 1 I required

the JavaScript ,I am getting in InnerHTML is like that

```
var l = new Array();
l[0] = '>';
l[1] = 'a';
l[2] = '/';
l[3] = '<';
l[4] = '|109';
l[5] = '|111';
l[6] 
l[52] = '|101';
l[53] = '|100';
l[54] = ':';
l[55] = 'o';
l[56] = 't';
l[57] = 'l';
l[58] = 'i';
l[59] = 'a';
l[60] = 'm';
l[61] = '"';
l[62] = '=';
l[63] = 'f';
l[64] = 'e';
l[65] = 'r';
l[66] = 'h';
l[67] = ' ';
l[68] = 'a';
l[69] = '<';
for (var i = l.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    if (l[i].substring(0, 1) == '|') document.write("&#" + unescape(l[i].substring(1)) + ";");
    else document.write(unescape(l[i]));
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you are trying to parse? More specifically the javascript that you are scraping? Also please show the regular expression you have attempted. BTW the reason why people use javascript in their sites to render email addresses is exactly to prevent scrapers like you to retrieve them easily.

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Dimitrov you are right , but how can I Grab it after document.write, I have downloaded an extension in firefox it is reading it , it is grabing the email address although it is rendered with Document.write